# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException occurring for @Bean annotated method

Tags: java, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have a class **ServerSentEventsConfig.java** that has a method annotated with @Bean & returning a org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter instance. I am trying to autowire this bean in a Controller class but I am getting a **UnsatisfiedDependencyException** on the class due to

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1466)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1097)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:589)
    ... 24 more
```

ServerSentEventsConfig.java

```
package com.forum.config;

@Configuration
public class ServerSentEventsConfig {

@Bean(name="userEventsEmmitter")
public ResponseBodyEmitter getEmmitter(){
    return new SseEmitter();
  }
}
```

UserActivityController.java

```
package com.forum.controllers;

@Controller
public class UserActivityController {

@Autowired
private UserActivityService userActivityService;

@Autowired
private SseEmitter userEventsEmmitter;


@RequestMapping("/userActivity")
public ResponseBodyEmitter  activityFeed() {
    return userEventsEmmitter;
}

}
```

Component scanning is already enabled in a applicationContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.forum.*"
    annotation-config="true" />
```

Not sure why the SseEmitter instance is not getting registered as a bean. What am I missing here ? Additionally I am extending **AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer**. Is there some conflicts happening because of that ?

```
@Order(1)
public class ApplicationInit extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {


@Override
protected WebApplicationContext createRootApplicationContext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new XmlWebApplicationContext();
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return new Class[] { UCFSecurityConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: Could it be that I am returning an instance of type ResponseBodyEmitter in the @Bean method & autowiring instance of type  SseEmitter in the controller ?

Comment: @configuration creates a bean of type ResponseBodyEmitter while u are autowiring SseEmitter.

Comment: does ResponseBodyEmitter extends SseEmitter ?

Comment: no, that doesn't seem like it. I changed the autowiring to ResponseBodyEmitter. still the same error

Comment: @wildthings81 would you show your class ResponseBodyEmitter and I suspect the package may be deeper as u have mentioned in the component scan.

Comment: also in your logs, u have mentioned NoSuchBeanDefinitionException while in the text u have mentioned UnsatisfiedDependencyException.

Comment: parent exception is UnsatisfiedDependencyException